# How to create simple Firefox Add-ons?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

How can I create and deploy a simple Add-on, just for altering the name of anything? How to create Add-ons for Mozilla firefox?

Comment: What do you mean by “the name of anything”?

Comment: You probably want to install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com). You can manipulate the DOM with it. That's way more easy than writing an extension yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you [read the Manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/building_an_extension) and it didn't give you enough information? You might try [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748/), but that also requires a little RTFM.

Answer (score 1):

Just by some quick googling i got this useful guide for creating addon for firefox

[creating addon for firefox](http://blog.mozilla.com/addons/2009/01/28/how-to-develop-a-firefox-extension/)